# OpenWRT + SQLite

Tags: linux, networking, router, mysql

I've got a personal project where I have Openwrt + Python + SQLite running in a small router with barely any space (16Mb). To store the database I am using a USB/SDcard attached to the router.

Periodically I would like to take the DB entries and store them in a remote MySQL Linux server so I can free some space.

What would be the best solution here? Implement MySQL in the router so the Linux server can remotely connect to the router and take the entries out or just download the .db file and convert it in the Linux Server into MySQL periodically? any other ides?

Comment: Is superuser the right place to ask this type of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to estimate or calculate, will you really use the entire space? For some marketing reasons we are thinking that 8Mb free space are really tight (comparing to Tb of the available HDDs). I figured out that my home automation on a GL-AR150 will keep the data of the next 5 years.

On some routers there is a possibility to add an SD card, external USB stick, or an HDD. Typically I'm storing some snapshots from my surveillance webcam by triggers. Why not to consider to host the entire DB on an external storage?

If you have a small amount of data (not loading you broadband at 100% for 2 days), you can schedule via cron a data upload to linux server. Basically the script is calling a remote php file which fetching the data from your sqlite db and inserting to mysql one. After what it's setting a flag to the uploaded rows, so you are not fetching it the next time. Or if you have an RTC, then the flag could be your router linux datetime, which you are keeping in mysql db.

Comment: Ey! Thanks for the great idea. I am currently storing the data in a SDcard as described in my question using the GL-MT300A. I was thinking of using Expect for python to download the DB daily to the linux server. How would the php look like? so the cron job will call the php which in turn will connect to the DB inn the router?

Comment: Well it depends on what are you using (PDO, procedural, etc.). But generally: conenct to SQLite > fetch the data array to a variable > connect to MySQL and insert the new data > check the inserted > setup an "uploaded" flag on the data in SQLite